# Issue with int pointer in C++

Tags: c++

```
int *sub(int *A,int q)
{
    int i = id(A,q)+1,j = id(A,q)-1;
    int *l , *m ;
    m = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *m = q;
    l = m ;
    for(i ; *(A+i) != '\0' && *(A + i) >= q ; ++i)
    {
      ++l = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
      *l = *(A+i);
    }
    ++l = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *l = '\0';
    for(j ; j>=0 && *(A + j) >= q  ; j--)
    {
        --m = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *m = *(A+i);
    }
    for(i = 0 ; *(m + i) != '\0' ; i++)
        cout<<*(m+i)<<"##\t";

    return m;
}
```

It's a function that is supposed to take a pointer to a 1D array (A) and then return a pointer to another 1D array(m) which is subarray of A and has elements greater than or equal to q(passed as parameter to the function `sub`)
I guess there is some problem with the way I manipulate int pointers.

Comment: If you `malloc`, you aren't doing `c++`.

Comment: This is exactly what [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is for. Please use that and return a container instead of a pointer that the caller now has to free along with like 50 memory leaks.

Comment: m is not a 2d array but you are treating it like one

Comment: Is there a ban on variable names longer than 1 character in your class? Why would you sabotage yourself like this, otherwise?

Comment: You might want to check the order of operation on things like "--m = malloc".  That might be compiler dependent.  And what exactly is your problem, anyway?

Comment: I see a lot of `malloc`s, but no `free`s ? And each malloc is only for one `int` ? This is nasty code bro'

Comment: One problem I see is that the calling function will have no idea how much space has been reserved for m, you definitely need to free l (which seems to be unneeded), and you're treating this as a sorted array, so there has do be an easier way to do this.

Comment: @NerfHerder, `--m` returns a reference to the decremented object. That reference is assigned a pointer. The decrement comes before the assignment, which is all that's necessary.

Comment: Oh, yeah, if the array comes in sorted, it's especially easy. Use `std::copy` with a call to `std::lower_bound` and you're done.

Comment: hey guys thanx for for useful inputs...realizing my sloppiness in c i have tried to achieve the task using STL heres my code but its still not working , the values getting stored in the subarrays' deque arent right,they seem like addresses when i print the subarrays

Comment: heres my code...http://ideone.com/45z3yA

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int q = 5;
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::copy_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [q](int i){return i >= q; });
    std::for_each(result.begin(), result.end(), [](int i){std::cout << i << std::endl; });
    getline(std::cin, std::string());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have no guarantee that m+i will ever be '\0', at least not for space that has been malloc'ed.

On top of the points mentioned in the comments, like making sure all space is freed appropriately.  This just looks like a big memory leak all over the place.